Error about Context when running react native for web
I'm trying to run my react navite app on Web and I get this error:
It works fine on iOS but when I try to add Stack.Navigator it just starts compalaining about Context.
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context')
useContext@
SafeAreaProviderCompat@
renderWithHooks@
mountIndeterminateComponent@
callCallback@
dispatchEvent@[native code]
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@
invokeGuardedCallback@
beginWork$1@

Here's my sample app
App.web.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'; // You may need this for safe area handling
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    // Wrapping with SafeAreaProvider for safe area support
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

Here's my Webpack
webpack.config.js:

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.web.js', // Point to the root-level index.js
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native-linear-gradient': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './react-native-linear-gradient.mock.js'
      ),
      'react-native-safe-area-context': path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './react-native-safe-area-context.mock.js'
      ),
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-reanimated': 'react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated2',
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.tsx'],
  },
};

Anybody seen this issue before?
